# How to find finish times of processes in cplex

Tags: scheduling, cplex

I have a machine,batch scheduling problem. Finish time of a batch is "Z[b]" variable. There are three machines(f represent machines). If a machine starts processing a specific batch at time t  X[f][b][t] equals to 1.
"P[b]" parameter is the proccesing time of the batches. I need to find ending times of batches.Tried this constraint.t is the range of time for example 48 hours.
"forall(p in B) Z[p]-(sum(n in F)sum(a in 1..t-P[p]+1)(a+P[p])*X[n][p][a])==0 ;"
I have 3 machines but this constraint just use 2 machines at time 1. Also Z[p] values is not logical.How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Within CPLEX you have CPOptimizer that is good at [scheduling](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=studio-scheduling-ilog-cplex).
And to get the end of an interval , endOf(itvs) works fine

Comment: I checked the endOf examples in the internet. They used in objective function. My objective function is electric cost of the machines. As i know there can be only one objective function. I think i have to find finish times of a batch in the constraints. Im new to cplex so i dont know what to do. Do you have any other advices? Thank you.